# Running vi from within haskell program (dealing with ptys)

Tags: linux, shell, haskell, pty

I'm trying to write a logging shell; e.g. one that captures data about commands that are being run in a structured format. To do this, I'm using `readline` to read in commands and then executing them in a subshell whilst capturing things such as the time taken, the environment, the exit status and so on.

So far so good. However, initial attempts to run things such as `vi` or `less` from within this logging shell failed. Investigation suggested that the thing to do was to establish a pseudo-tty and connect the subshell to that rather than to a normal pipe. This stops vi complaining about not being connected to a terminal, but still fails - I get some nonsense printed to the screen and commands print as characters in the editor - e.g. 'ESC' just displays `^[`.

I *thought* that what I needed to do was put the pty in raw mode. To do this, I tried the following:

```
  pty <- do
    parentTerminal <- getControllingTerminalName >>= 
                      \a -> openFd a ReadWrite Nothing defaultFileFlags
    sttyp <- getTerminalAttributes parentTerminal
    (a, b) <- openPseudoTerminal
    let rawModes = [ProcessInput, KeyboardInterrupts, ExtendedFunctions, 
                    EnableEcho, InterruptOnBreak, MapCRtoLF, IgnoreBreak, 
                    IgnoreCR, MapLFtoCR, CheckParity, StripHighBit, 
                    StartStopOutput, MarkParityErrors, ProcessOutput]
        sttym = withoutModes rawModes sttyp
        withoutModes modes tty = foldl withoutMode tty modes
    setTerminalAttributes b sttym Immediately
    setTerminalAttributes a sttym Immediately
    a' <- fdToHandle a
    b' <- fdToHandle b
    return (a',b')
```

E.g. we get the parent terminal's attributes, remove the various flags that I think correspond to setting the tty into raw mode (based on [this code](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/C/system/ttyraw.c) and [the haddock for `System.Posix.Terminal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.5.1.0/docs/src/System-Posix-Terminal-Common.html#TerminalMode)), and then set these on both sides of the pty.

I then start up a process within a shell using `createProcess` and use `waitForProcess` to connect to it, giving the slave side of the pty for the stdin and stdout handles on the child process:

```
eval :: (Handle, Handle) -> String -> IO ()
eval pty command = do
    let (ptym, ptys) = pty
    (_, _, hErr, ph) <- createProcess $ (shell command) { 
          delegate_ctlc = True
        , std_err = CreatePipe
        , std_out = UseHandle ptys
        , std_in = UseHandle ptys
      }
    snipOut <- tee ptym stdout
    snipErr <- sequence $ fmap (\h -> tee h stderr) hErr
    exitCode <- waitForProcess ph
    return ()
  where tee :: Handle -> Handle -> IO B.ByteString
        tee from to = DCB.sourceHandle from
            $= DCB.conduitHandle to -- Sink contents to out Handle
            $$ DCB.take 256 -- Pull off the start of the stream
```

This definitely changes terminal settings (confirmed with `stty`), but doesn't fix the problem. Am I missing something? Is there some other device I need to set attributes on?

Edit: The full runnable code is available at https://github.com/nc6/tabula - I've simplified a few things for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jamshidh pointed out that I wasn't actually connecting my stdin to the master side of the pty, so the issues I was getting were nothing to do with vi or terminal modes, and entirely to do with not passing in any input!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you create the `vi` process:

```
(_, _, hErr, ph) <- createProcess $ (shell command) {
```

Those return values are `stdin/stdout/stderr`.  You throw away `stdin/stdout` (and keep `stderr`).  You will need those to communicate with `vi`.  Basically, when you type in `ESC`, it isn't even getting to the process.

As a larger architectural note- You are rewriting not just the terminal code, but a full REPL/shell script....  This is a larger project than you probably want to get into (go read the bash manual to see all the stuff they needed to implement).  You might want to consider wrapping around a user choosable shell script (like bash).  Unix is pretty modular this way, that is why xterm, ssh, the command prompt etc all work the same way- they proxy the chosen shell script, rather than each write their own.

Comment: Throwing away those handles is correct - they are attached to the slave side of a pty, which I hold on to the master side of. However, you have inadvertently pointed out that I don't actually connect my stdin to the master! So that might be a problem :-)